# App_id spoofing and misuse

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication, facebook-wall, spoofing

Sorry if this is too basic a question for this forum but it's been playing on my mind for a while so I tried it out. I used the IMDB app_id and a spoof URL, image etc and it came back with an error message saying that I wasn't allowed to do that. Good. Tried the same thing with my App ID and it sailed straight through without a hitch! Spoof wall posting appeared as if it came from my app! Could have been absolutely anything! Porn, phishing attack, you name it!

So my question is what have I missed. How come only IMDB is allowed to use their App ID but any Tom, Dick or Harry can use mine?!

Comment: Ok, here's one of my app ids (113830492072210), can you show me a spoof (make the post public please) of where you used my app id to make a posting?

Comment: @DMCS sure here is an example: http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=307871105936031&id=100001394318772

Comment: Yeah, freaky.  I'd submit this to http://www.facebook.com/whitehat and earn yourself some bucks.

Comment: I don't see why its a big deal though? App ID's are super easy to find for apps and there is no way to limit this (although I havent tried IMDB's yet)

Comment: Here is a [post as IMDB](http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=308215345901607&id=100001394318772). It's really not an issue though.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you can do to secure your apps against this, if you're worried.

1. Turn on `Stream post URL security` setting in your Dev App settings (under Advanced > Migrations). This will prevent stream posts from your App ID from linking to anything other than your Apps connect or canvas URLs.
2. Edit the `Server Whitelist` (under Advanced > Security settings) to only include your apps server IP address. This will mean that only API requests coming from those specified IPs will be accepted.

Comment: It's important to note it shouldn't be possible for you to get an access token for an arbitrary user/app combination, only for your own user or your own app - if you're talking about the feed dialog, that's less restrictive, but what Matthew says above is valid and should prevent posts attributed to your app that you don't have control over