# How risky is publishing your App Id when using feed dialog?

Tags: security, facebook-graph-api, app-id

I'm concerned that when I use Facebook's feed dialog I'm making my App Id public and thus open to exploitation. Is there much risk in my App Id being public? IF yes, what are those risks?Are there any ways that I can minimise those risks?

**EDIT:** The examples I've been looking at make use of the Javascript SDK, so getting the App ID would be relatively easy. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I haven't seen any examples using the PHP SDK, but I think the App ID would still be present in the URL.

**EDIT2:** Found some more information here [App_id spoofing and misuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337180/app-id-spoofing-and-misuse)

Comment: You don't have to afraid about the public id, only the app secret and tokens, but why you are printing the id to the client side?

Comment: If you use the direct URL Example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ The App ID is in the actual URL.

Comment: i see..., but it's not a problem, the only thing someone can do with this id, is to put your app in his/her fanpage tab, but if you ask for permissions you have to redirect the users to your url, so it's fine! don't worry about the id!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no risk. Your `Application ID` is already public information. It's your `Application Secret` that you can't leak.